# How can I see the created date of a node in a view?

Tags: views, 8

How can I see the created date of a node in a view? I don't see it as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choose revision, created date as the field to add in the view

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77818)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer she answered her own question...